# Optimize Comparision of list in scala using case match

Tags: scala

I have a list of Futures and I want to compare them.
Is there any better way to check empty checks .I have uses exhaustive case match

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val list1 = Future(List("abc","xyz"))
val list2 = Future(List("def","ghk"))

for{
  l1 <- list1
  l2 <- list2
} yield {
  ( l1.nonEmpty,l2.nonEmpty) match{
    case (true , true) => //perform task
    case (false , true) => // print error as l1 is empty
    case (true , false) => //print error as l2 is empty
      case(false, false) => //print error as l2 and l1 is empty 
  }
}
```

Comment: This depends on a lot of things, including exactly what you want your errors to look like. The simplest version probably involves `Future#filter` and `zip`.

Comment: If you want to do something different for each scenario, you will need a different case for each scenario. If you just want to do _something_ if one fails, something like [Mahmoud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832557/8230810) will do fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check if l1 & l2 are non empty only you don't have to match the other cases:

```
  (l1.nonEmpty,l2.nonEmpty) match {
    case (true , true) => //perform task
    case (e1, e2) => println(s"Error l1 or l2 are empty, l1 nonEmpty: $e1, l2 nonEmpty: $e2")
  }
```

if you don't want to log the error at all you can check at the for:

```
for{
  l1 <- list1
  l2 <- list2
  if l1.nonEmpty && l2.nonEmpty
} yield {
```